# Is it safe to call gst_bus_set_sync_handler on GStreamer pipeline bus?

Tags: c++, gstreamer

To get all bus messages from my GStreamer pipelines, I am currently calling `gst_bus_set_sync_handler` (returning `GST_BUS_DROP` from my handler). This seems to work perfectly as far as I can tell, but the documentation states:

> This function is usually only called by the creator of the bus.
>   Applications should handle messages asynchronously using the gst_bus
>   watch and poll functions.

Should I be worried? I assume that the "creator of the bus" is not the same as the creator of the pipeline (me), or is it?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple considerations I'm aware of regarding the use of `gst_bus_set_sync_handler`.

Firstly, since it runs your code synchronously in the same thread that posted the message, you'll be blocking that thread from doing other work for as long as your callback runs. If you do a fair bit of work when handling a message, this could cause performance issues.

Secondly, you may not reliably be able to use `gst_element_set_state` in a synchronous message handler, because elements are not allowed to set their own state in their streaming thread. Whether or not this is a problem will depend on which streaming thread in the pipeline sent the message, something you normally don't have to worry about in asynchronous messaging handlers.

I would recommend using asynchronous messaging whenever possible, as it has fewer caveats. On the other hand, if `gst_bus_set_sync_handler` works for you, using it shouldn't be a problem.